# LCM multiple subscribers conflict

Tags: lcm

I'm using LCM (https://lcm-proj.github.io/lcm/) to pass messages between two computers, and one issue I'm having is that when I try to have two processes/threads/programs subscribe to the same channel, only one of them seems to work.

If I start one, the subscribe callback runs fine. If I then start the second program, it now gets the messages but the first one stop receiving anything. If I kill the second program, the first one starts getting messages again.

Is there a way around this? Does LCM support this? What might I be doing wrong?